# Add multiple user accounts of the same gmail in firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create multiple user accounts with the same email address, but I'm not sure how. For example, I want two users to have two different accounts, even though they share the same email address (as long as their password is different). Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Are you using firebase authentication?  If so then you cannot do this. The email address is the user account.

Comment: @Coder44, as Paulw11 already mentioned, the email address is the user. Now, I have 2 options in mind that may help. #1 use an additional authentication method, e.g. facebook. #2 use only one user with multiple user profiles, similar to Netflix, Disney+ or Amazon Prime Video, you log in with just one email, but from there the user can choose its profile, if you want to, the profile could be locked by a pin or so.